# Erro ao registrar informações no banco de dado

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, comecei a aprender php e mysql a pouco tempo. No momento estou tentando fazer uma espécie de sistema de postagens, mas não estou conseguindo gravar as informações no DB. Se puderem ajudar a encontrar o que tem de errado, será ótimo 
 :).

Um formulário é submetido e o action manda para esse arquivo:

```
<?php

require_once('db.class.php');

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$texto_postagem = $_POST['descricao'];

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$data = date("d/m/Y");
$hora = date("H:i");

$objDb = new db();
$link = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();

$sql = "insert into postagens(titulo, descricao, data, hora) values($titulo', '$texto_postagem', '$data', '$hora') ";

//executar a query
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo 'Postagem armazenada com sucesso';
} else {
    echo 'Erro ao registrar postagem!';
}
```

?>

E esse arquivo chama esse:

```
<?php
class db {

    private $host = 'localhost';

    private $usuario = 'root';

    private $senha = '';

    private $database = 'sistema_postagens';

    public function conecta_mysql(){

        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->database);


        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo 'Erro ao tentar se conectar com o BD MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error();  
        }

        return $con;

    }
}
?>
```

Quando roda, aparece o echo 'Erro ao registrar postagem!'

Comment: Se você não sabe o que está errado, não mascare o erro com uma mensagem que não te ajuda em nada. Ao invés de exibir mensagens como "Vish! Deu erro" exiba a mensagem real do erro com a função `mysqli_error`. Aliás, falta uma aspa simples antes de `$titulo` na sua SQL.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Consegui encontrar o erro com mysqli_error :)

Answer (score 0):

Você se esqueceu da aspas no inicio do titulo em values

```
<?php

require_once('db.class.php');

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$texto_postagem = $_POST['descricao'];

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$data = date("d/m/Y");
$hora = date("H:i");

$objDb = new db();
$link = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();
//AQUI VOCÊ ESQUECEU Da aspas mude $titulo' para '$titulo'
$sql = "insert into postagens(titulo, descricao, data, hora) values('$titulo', '$texto_postagem', '$data', '$hora') ";

//executar a query
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo 'Postagem armazenada com sucesso';
} else {
    echo 'Erro ao registrar postagem!';
}
```